# Convert Amazon S3 object LastModified column time zone from UTC to EST

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, jmespath

I am using a JMESPath query to filter out files from S3 objects based on LastModified date. S3 LastModified date is in UTC so I have to convert to EST.

Is there a function in JSMEPath Query which can convert from UTC to EST?

My query is:

```
aws s3api list-objects  --bucket mybucket --prefix folder --query 'Contents[*][Key,LastModified>=`2017-02-21T11:09:41.000Z` && LastModified<=`2017-02-22T11:09:41.000Z`]' --output text | grep -i True | grep -i file_search_pattern | sed -e 's/True//g'
```

Comment: Why do you have to convert to EST?

Comment: I am doing incremental ingestion from s3 to hadoop, my audit tables are in  hadoop which are in EST time zone so I would like to convert LastModified column time to est before applying filter.